# How to find a random line in a file in c?

Tags: c, file-io

The code I have so far is this but it runs a bus 10 error i'm new to c so any help would be appreciated

```
FILE *ptrFile;
ptrFile = fopen("/Users/ryanremer/NetBeansProjects/Hangman/movies.txt","r");   
int count = 0;
seek(ptrFile, 0, SEEK_END);   
count = ftell(ptrFile);
printf("%i",count);

srand(time(NULL));
random = rand()%count;
fseek(ptrFile,random, SEEK_SET );

char *printLine;
fgets(printLine,200,ptrFile); // skip a line incase random place is in middle of line
printLine= fgets(printLine,200,ptrFile);
printf("%s",printLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
char *printLine;
fgets(printLine,200,ptrFile);
```

you define a pointer with name `printLine` that does not point anywhere valid. Immediatelt afterwards you try to write something at the address pointed to by that pointer.
Don't do that!

First, make sure the pointer points to some valid address with enough space for the input.